# Very simple question regarding JavaScript and login

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this JS code, its supposed to output the stuff I put into the email and password boxes on the console, so in the future I can put them into a database.

My problem is, that the first time I execute my code, it works as expected, the second time I do it, the code only displays the last console.log() prompt.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
let email;
let password;

document.getElementById("loginBtn").onclick = function(){
  email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  console.log(email);
  password = document.getElementById("password").value;
console.log(password);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" > 
    <h3 id="LogInToAcc" class="fonts"> Log into your account.</h3> 
    <hr>
   <p class="fonts" id="accDont">Don't have an account?</p>
   <a class="fonts" id="SignUp" href="signup.html"> Sign up!</a><br><br>
    
    
 <label class="inputlabel" for="email">Email:</label> <br> 

 <input  id="email" class="inputs" type="email" > <br><br>

 <label class="inputlabel" for="password"  >Password:</label> <br>

 <input id="password" class="inputs"  type="password" pattern=".{5,10}"> <br><br>
 <a  class="forgot"  href="newpassword">Forgot your password?</a>
 <a href="">
 <button id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" > Login</button> <br><br>
</a>

</div>

<script src="login.js"></script>
```

Some of the things I tried was, moving the code around. Setting the variables inside the function.

Comment: [Use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/). You can't put a button inside a link.

Comment: Just a note: in general, it's invalid and very bad to nest interactive elements, such as your button inside an anchor. If it's for styling, just style it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Clicking the button inside the links to causes the link to be followed and a new page loaded.

Comment: @Quentin add # into href, plus i dont see any problem as described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily, your HTML is not valid. After restructuring it and tweaking the JavaScript, you get something like what I've got below.

Be sure to read the comments.

```js
// Get you element references just once rather than 
// every time the function runs. Also, don't set the
// variables up to point to a property of the element
// so that in case you need to access a different 
// property later, you won't need to scan for the 
// element reference again.
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const password = document.getElementById("password");

// Set up events the modern way
document.getElementById("loginBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(email.value, password.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <h1 id="LogInToAcc" class="fonts"> Log into your account.</h1> 
  <p class="fonts" id="accDont">Don't have an account?</p>
  <p><a class="fonts" id="SignUp" href="signup.html"> Sign up!</a></p>
  <div><label class="inputlabel" for="email">Email:</label></div>
  <div><input  id="email" class="inputs" type="email"></div>
  <div><label class="inputlabel" for="password"  >Password:</label></div>
  <div><input id="password" class="inputs"  type="password" pattern=".{5,10}"></div>
  <div><a class="forgot"  href="newpassword">Forgot your password?</a></div>
  <div><button id="loginBtn" class="loginBtn" > Login</button></div>
</div>

<script src="login.js"></script>
```